# Django + postgreSQL : why migrating did work even though I hadn't given my db info?

Tags: django, postgresql, migrate

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test',
    }
}
```

It's my settings.py. DATABASE 'test' has password, but I did not enter it.

and for testing, I tried migrating: [image: It looks like working well]

creating superuser did work, too. and psql,

[image]

I thought Django cannot connected with DB because I hadn't enter 'USER', 'PASSWORD' fields, but data was in my db. How could it work?

Comment: Is the database updated. It might be that you did not specify the proper settings file, in which case it will work with `sqlite` and thus construct an sqlite in the file system.

Comment: Not really sure, but you could have a [.pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-pgpass.html) file.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

fixed pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

After alter METHOD : trust to md5 and restart postgres, it works properly with 'USER' or 'PASSWORD' fields.